# Implementing Conditional Envers Auditing (Hibernate 4.3.7.Final)

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

I want to audit ALL properties in my entity but only if some properties has changed.
Following the steps described in the documentation ([here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch15.html#d5e4477)), I`ve create my own implementation of EnversIntegrator :

```
public class EnversIntegrator extends org.hibernate.envers.event.spi.EnversIntegrator {
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EnversIntegrator.class);  
private AuditConfiguration enversConfiguration;
@Override
public void integrate(Configuration configuration, SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory, SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
    log.debug(".... integrate");
    final EventListenerRegistry listenerRegistry = serviceRegistry.getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);
    listenerRegistry.addDuplicationStrategy(EnversListenerDuplicationStrategy.INSTANCE);
    enversConfiguration = AuditConfiguration.getFor(configuration, serviceRegistry.getService(ClassLoaderService.class));
    if (enversConfiguration.getEntCfg().hasAuditedEntities()) {
        log.debug(".... Register listeners");
        listenerRegistry.prependListeners(EventType.POST_DELETE, new MyPostDeleteEventListener(enversConfiguration));
        listenerRegistry.prependListeners(EventType.POST_INSERT, new MyPostInsertEnversEventListener(enversConfiguration));
        listenerRegistry.prependListeners(EventType.POST_UPDATE, new  MyPostUpdateEnversEventListener(enversConfiguration));
    }
}
@Override
public void disintegrate(SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory, SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
    if (enversConfiguration != null) {
        enversConfiguration.destroy();
    }
}
```

Where :

```
MyPostInsertEnversEventListener extends org.hibernate.envers.event.spi.EnversPostInsertEventListenerImpl
```

and

```
 MyPostUpdateEnversEventListener extends org.hibernate.envers.event.spi.EnversPostUpdateEventListenerImpl
```

Overriding onPostUpdate or onPostInsert(PostInsertEvent evt) has no effect, every time when I execute my test, a new record is added in _AUD table.

```
public void onPostUpdate(PostUpdateEvent evt) {     
    LOG.debug(" ... onPostUpdate " + evt.getEntity().getClass());
//here is my logic who decide if the super.onPostUpdate(evt) must be call or not  
//But NO  super.onPostUpdate(evt); is called !!!!!
```

}

Updating Address entity booth onPostUpdate and onPostInsert is called:

```
[DEBUG] xxxx.hibernate.MyPostUpdateEnversEventListener -  ... onPostUpdate class xxxxxxx.model.Address
[DEBUG] xxxx.hibernate.MyPostInsertEnversEventListener -  ... onPostInsert class org.hibernate.envers.DefaultRevisionEntity
[DEBUG] xxxx.hibernate.MyPostInsertEnversEventListener -  ... onPostInsert class java.util.HashMap
```

How can I prevent this new record creation in the _aud table?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugging the code I`ve realize that "integrate" method in org.hibernate.envers.event.spi.EnversIntegrator is called too. In fact i've misplaced "*hibernate.listeners.envers.autoRegister*" parameter in spring configuration. This is my working configuration :

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myTestDataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="xyz.**.model" />

    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaAdapter" />
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>             
                      <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.listeners.envers.autoRegister">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation"
        value="classpath:spring/app-persistence.xml" />
</bean>
```

Thx Adam four your great work.

Answer (score 2):

For newer versions the property is **`hibernate.envers.autoRegisterListeners`** and not `hibernate.listeners.envers.autoRegister`.
The last is only a legacy one. You can check `EnversIntegrator` and `EnversServiceImpl` classes for that.

For spring boot you can set with:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.envers.autoRegisterListeners=false
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to sublcass the event listeners, e.g. the `PostInsertEnversEventListener`, do the conditional auditing checks there, and call the super method if the check passes.

Comment: PostInsertEnversEventListener (now MyPostInsertEnversEventListener) is my implementation. I didn`t call super.onPostInsert(evt) or super.onPostUpdate. I`ve reduce my test only to see if I can control this insertion. Updating my entity, Envers calls onPostUpdate - with my test entity, and two times onPostInsert with org.hibernate.envers.DefaultRevisionEntity and java.util.HashMap. Apparently another listener insert a new record in _AUD, totally ignoring my code. I was wander if Envers has something like event.preventDefault() in jQuery.